# Getting total length of polyline from Leaflet draw?

Tags: leaflet, line, length, leaflet-draw

I'm quite new when it comes to Leaflet and this is my very first question asked here so I'm not experienced. While I was drawing polyline I noticed that you can get current distance while drawing it:
[image]
But I was wondering is there any method in Leaflet.Draw which can get the total distance of a created polyline so I can use it later?
**Edit:** As suggested this is the only code I have for now which is a basic map with some plugins:

```
var center = [42.6194, 25.3930];

var map = L.map('map', {
    fullscreenControl: true, fullscreenControlOptions: {
        position: 'topleft'
    },
    visualClick: true,
    visualClickPane: 'shadowPane'
}).setView(center, 7);


L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> | &copy; <a href="https://opentopomap.org/about">OpenTopoMap</a> | &copy; <a href="/">Trails</a>'
}).addTo(map);

var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(editableLayers);

var drawPluginOptions = {
    position: 'topleft',
    draw: {
        polyline: {
            shapeOptions: {
                color: '#c700ac',
                weight: 4
            }
        },
        polygon: false,
        circle: false,
        rectangle: false,
        circlemarker: false,
        marker: false
    },
    edit: {
        featureGroup: editableLayers,
        remove: false
    }
};

var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw(drawPluginOptions);
map.addControl(drawControl);

L.control.mousePosition().addTo(map);
L.control.scale().addTo(map);

var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(editableLayers);

map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    editableLayers.addLayer(e.layer);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that neither Leaflet nor Leaflet.Draw has some method to get line length, so you'll have to calculate it yourselves.

One way to do it is to use line layer `.getLatLngs()` method to get all line coordinates, and then loop through them and get line segments lengths (in meters) with Leaflet coordinate `.distanceTo` method.

Code could then look something like this:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
  var layer = e.layer;
  editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
  if (e.layerType = 'polyline') {
    var coords = layer.getLatLngs();
    var length = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < coords.length - 1; i++) {
      length += coords[i].distanceTo(coords[i + 1]);
    }
    console.log(length);
  }
});
```

Comment: Works! Thank you!